CMake how can I link multiple .so files?
I am fairly new to Cmake, what I am trying to do is use a shared library libA.so. Now I managed to import it fine and when I tried it in my code, it said that there are two dependency that is needed by the shared library which is also a shared libs say libB.so and libC.so
The problem is when I try to link these libB.so with LibC.so the Cmake keeps complaining that I can only link it as an INTERFACE... which I did and then when I run my program it still fails becaue libA.so cannot find symbols from libB.so and libC.so (likely because it is an INTERFACE link)
My quesion is how can I link these libs together? If I cannot do it with target_link_libraries what is another way to do it? My make file is as follows:
add_target(A SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION pathToSoFile/libA.so)

add_target(BSHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(B PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION pathToSoFile/libB.so)

add_target(C SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(C PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION pathToSoFile/libC.so)

target_link_libraries(A INTERFACE B C)

My main CMakeLists.txt looks like this
add_library(main SHARED main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main A)

somethings I have already tried are:

Add B and C to the target_link_libraries of main tareget_link_libraries(main A B C)->didnt work
Add B and C to individual sub directories with their own CMakeLists.txt and then using add_subdirectory call -> didnt work

I can see the libA.so, libB.so and libC.so in the intermedaites folder and they are available... but for some reason libA is not able to find the symbols link to libB and libC which by my guess is because of the target_link_libraries is not allowing PUBLIC or PRIVATE link and only INTERFACE link for the SHARED IMPORTED libs.... Any thoughts on how I can go about this?

"but for some reason libA is not able to find the symbols link to libB and libC which by my guess is because of the target_link_libraries is not allowing ..." - No, your guess is wrong. A correct shared library by itself contains all needed linkage. A linker error means that something goes wrong with your libraries. Most likely, CMake is unrelated to your problem. Add to the question post the exact error message, otherwise we simply cannot help you.

I did come across this issue which was created around a year back requesting something more or less same as what I expressed above (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23426) Maybe in the future it might support. I understand your comment about shared libraries being self contained but in this scenario it isnt, I think since I have the libs are opensource, I can try to statically link libB and libC to libA and the make it shared though I wanted to avoid that. Thanks for your reply!

I didn't say that a shared library is self-contained. I said that a shared library knows every linkage it needs. That is, if creation of libA involves linking with libB, then given linkage is stored in libA, so whenever you link with libA the linker automatically searches for libB too. I don't know why you refer to the bugreport about the library created by the CMake project: your case is absolutely different as it is about already existed libraries.
